# Rotate Circular Images

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

Hello I'm going to do text detection on circular images.
After some preprocessing I do polar to cartesian transformation on images

this is example of my real image

[image: this is my real image]

after doing p2c transformation my images become like

[image: p2c transofrmation]

but since my images come in a different angles sometimes p2c transformation cut out my characters

[image: cutted char]

I think I need to do proper rotation before p2c transformation.

my question is what kind of rotation method is proper for this situation? or should I start p2c transformation based on histogram values ? or what kind of other ways would you guys suggest me?

thanks

Comment: you could use [`circshift`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) on your result image data. That would translate the text until your desired position.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do your polar to cartesian transformation and analyse your resulting image `X`. You can find you letters by summing all values along the x dimension and using a threshold to detect if there is a letter or not:

```
y = sum(X,1);
th = (max(y) + min(y)) / 2;
letters = y < th;
```

Now you can find out if there is a letter at the border of the image and shift the image if this is the case.

```
if sum(letters([1:10,end-10:end]))
   X = circshift(X,[0,10]);
end
```

Of course you can't be sure that there is no letter at the border now, so better loop this procedure until no letter is found at the border.

Comment: hello is there any methods on literature that I can use ?